# Using an extension of AuthorizeAttribute causes the Roles restriction to be ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, attributes

I have the following extension of the AuthorizeAttribute (taken with minor modifications from http://johnskdev.com/prevent-concurrent-logins-from-a-single-user-account-in-net/):

```
 public class AuthorizeSingleLogin : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        bool isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);

        string user = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;

        string access = httpContext.Session.SessionID;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(user) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(access))
        {
            return isAuthorized;
        }

        SQLLoginrecord sqlLogin = new SQLLoginrecord();

        return sqlLogin.IsLoggedIn(user, access);
    }
}
```

And in my Controller, I have:

```
    [AuthorizeSingleLogin(Roles = "Users11")]
    public ActionResult User11Action()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

The problem is, this still lets me access the User11 View page even for a user who is not in that role. When I change the attribute to just Authorize, as follows:

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Users11")]
    public ActionResult User11Action()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I get the access denied page that I expect from my app. How can I fix this so the extended AuthorizeSingleLogin respects the parameters that its parent supports?

Thank you.

Comment: you can't use both attributes? `[AuthorizeSingleLogin], [Authorize(Roles = "Users11")]`

Comment: @JamieD77 that works great, thanks. I am still new to .NET MVC and I assumed it would be the usual object oriented way of the child having the features of the parent class, but I guess it is different for annotations...